# Error exporting from emacs to latex with org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I use org mode in emacs to export to latex and pdf file I have a problem. When I export to latex file, it's OK. but when I process latex file to export PDF file, I have this error:

```
Process completed with errors: [undefined control sequence] [LaTeX error]
```

Please tell me, how I can fix it.

Comment: Is this specific to a certain file? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at the .log file, if any, in the same directory (where the LaTeX compilation occurred).

Best (IMHO) is to compile the TeX file directly (using AUCTeX, if within Emacs), and to have a finer control on what's going wrong in the LaTeX route.

Comment: And what if there's no .log file?

Comment: How can that be?  Who's deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 24 (maybe even in earlier versions) there is variable called `org-latex-remove-logfiles`, by default it is set to `on`, toggle it to `off` and latex will keep the log files.

To get to it, in Emacs do

`M-x RET customize-variable RET org-latex-remove-logfiles`